# Voice over outline taking more height, which looks ugly on the page

Tags: html, css, accessibility, voiceover

[image]

I am supporting voice-over functionality in my webpage and I noticed something odd. The outline that is visible around the element is taking lots of height due to the length of the text.

```
<span class="outer-box">
    <span class="a11y">Last page updated.</span>
    2 mins ago
</span>

.outer-box {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.a11y {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGxWoW

If you are using a Mac + voice-over, when you over the the element(class=a11y) you would see the voice-over outline taking more height.

I would like if there is some way you could regulate that height.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an example where a visually hidden text does not improve the accessibility. While the "Last page updated" is important for everyone to understand what the text "2 mins ago" means, you hide it and it will benefit to a minor part of the population using a screenreader.*

Voiceover defines a minimum size for the visual focus in order for it to be visible.

The best solution is to make the text visible. This will help everyone.